# How can i pass extra variable in symfony form builForm Function

Tags: php, forms, symfony

THis my code

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options , $task )
    {
        $builder
            ->add('genTasks','text',array('label'=>$task->getName()))

        ;
    }
```

Is there any way i can access the $task variable inside buildForm

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but isn't $task being passed into the function buildForm (your third parameter)?  So, you have access to it, right?

Comment: I tried that and it gives error. it says that builform should match as written in symfony form class. so i can't pass in that function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
{
    $task = $options['task'];

    // If you want...
    if(is_null($task)) throw new \LogicException('Task option is required.');

    $builder
        ->add('genTasks', 'text', array('label' => $task->getName()))
    ;
}

public function getDefaultOptions(array $options)
{
    return $options + array('task' => null);
}
```

And pass your task object as option when you create your form.