# Symfony2 : how to embed a collection of forms with variable labels?

Tags: forms, symfony-2.1

Thanks to [this help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11822675/how-can-i-pass-extra-variable-in-symfony-form-builform-function) I can create a form with variable labels.
Now I want to create a collection of such forms, but I can't do that.

Precisely : I have a MyField  class:

```
class MyField {
    protected label;
    protected userAnswer;

    public function setLabel($label){...}
    public function getLabel(){...}
    public function setUserAnswer($answer){...}
    public function getUserAnswer(){...}
}
```

I also have a MyFieldType class :

```
class MyFieldType extends AbstractType{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options){
        $myField = $options['myField'];
        $builder->add('userAnswer', 'text', array('label' => $myField->getLabel()));
    }

    public function getDefaultOptions(array $options){
        return array('data_class' => '...\MyField',
                        'myField' => null);
    }
}
```

And, in a controller :

```
public function MyAction(Request $request){
    ...
    $myField = new MyField();
    ...
    $form = $this->createForme(new MyFieldType(), $myField, array('myField' => $myField));
    ...
}
```

With all that, fields labels are $myField->label.

Now I want to create a form with several MyFields : I have a class MyForm

```
class MyForm {
    protected myFields; // array of MyField
    public function setMyFields...
    public function getMyFields...
    public function addAField...
}
```

And I still want field labels as $myField->label. So, **how can I define MyFormType ?**
I tried something like :

```
class MyFormType extends AbstractType {
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options){
        $myFields = $options['myFields'];
        $builder->add('myFields', 'collection',
                array('type' => new MyFieldType(),
                    'options' => array('myField' => $myFields[0])));
    }
```

It works (and of course all fields have the same label, and I don't want that), but I can't figure how to give each MyFieldType its own MyField...

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

I would create these two Types:

```
class MyFormType extends AbstractType {

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options){

        $builder->add('myFields', 'collection',
                array('type' => new MyFieldType());
    }




class MyFieldType extends AbstractType {
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options){

        $builder->add('label', 'text');
    }
```

Hope it helps

Comment: This is almost what I want. With your solution I can see customized labels for each field, but they are inside the fields (like placeholders). What I need is to see them as labels... Ideally, I would like to have a form type that would not ask users to answer (a form type that is not really a form type). It would just be there to display labels.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a way to do what I want (thanks to nass600's answer and my reply) :
I have created a new type of field (see http://symfony.com/en/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html) like this :

```
class LabelType extends AbstractType{
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver){
    }

    public function getParent(){
        return 'text';
    }

    public function getName(){
        return 'label';
    }
}
```

Then, I have changed MyFieldType :

```
class MyFieldType extends AbstractType{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options){
        $builder->add('label', new LabelType())
                ->add('userAnswer', 'text');
    }

    public function getDefaultOptions(array $options){
        return array('data_class' => '...\MyField')
    }
}
```

I have also created a fields.html.twig, like explained in Symfony cookbook, with just :

```
{% block label_widget %}
  {{ value }}
{% endblock %}
```

And, now, in my myForm.html.twig :

```
...
{% for field in form.myFields %}
{% form_widget(field.label) %}
{% form_widget(field.userAnswer) %}
...
```

which works with :

```
class MyFormType extends AbstractType {
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options){
        $myFields = $options['myFields'];
        $builder->add('myFields', 'collection',
                array('type' => new MyFieldType()));
    }
...
```

Bye