# passing variable from a from to the controller symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

Here is the code of my form:

```
 class CentrexEdit1Type extends AbstractType
    {
        public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
        {       
            $builder          
                ->add('bases', 'entity', array(
                  'class'    => 'TelnOperatorBundle:Base',
                  'property' => 'name',
                  'multiple' => true,

                ));
            $ids= $builder->getData()->getBases();  

        }

        public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
        {
            $resolver->setDefaults(array(
                'data_class' => 'Teln\OperatorBundle\Entity\Centrex'
            ));
        }



        public function getName()
        {
            return 'teln_operatorbundle_centrextype';
        }   

    }
```

I need to pass the variable `$ids= $builder->getData()->getBases();` from   "CentrexType" to the controller. 
Should I use a service? 
I tried getSession but it failed.
How to do that?

Example: where I have to add the query_builder

```
class CentrexEdit2Type extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {


    $builder->add('softswitchs', 'entity', array(
              'class'    => 'TelnOperatorBundle:Softswitch',
              'property' => 'name',
              'multiple' => true,
              'query_builder' => function(\Teln\OperatorBundle\Entity\SoftswitchRepository $er) use ($ids)
                                         {

                                        $identities=array();
                                        foreach($ids as $id){
                                        $identities[]=$id->getId();
                                        }
                                         $qb = $er->createQueryBuilder('t')
                                                  ->where('t.base IN(:ids)')
                                                  ->setParameter('ids', $identities); 

                                          return $qb;

                                          },
               ));


    }
```

Comment: Do you need to specifically need to pass the data back from the form to the controller? Could you not just access the repository in the controller and get the `$ids` from there? What actually is it that you are trying to do?

Comment: I want to get the content of the variable ids because later I will use it on query_builder for other entities. I'll join the example.

Comment: You could set the `$ids` variable and then pass that in the constructor to each form that needs to use it using `createForm(new CentrexType($ids), $entity)` if that's how you do your forms.

Comment: I find this solution to add in the controller
 $form->get('dueDate')->getData();  
but now how to pass it from the controller to the form ?

Comment: `$form->etc->getData()` is used for getting actual user data from the form rather than the base form elements.

Comment: thank u for the solution this is exactly what I needed.the problem now is how to declare it in the form itself ie here  public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11822675/how-can-i-pass-extra-variable-in-symfony-form-builform-function I found out this discussion but what does he mean by pass your task object as option when you create your form.

Comment: I believe you would either pass the through as '$form = $this->createForm(new TaskType(), $task, array(options));' or you could pass it into the `__construct()` of the formType using `$form = $this->createForm(new TaskType($ids), $task);`